# Не работает наследование через свойство прототип

Tags: наследование, prototype, ооп, javascript

Пытаюсь разобраться с ООП в js

столкнулся с такой проблемой
есть 2 класса, один унаследован от другого через прототип
класс родителя добавлен метод set
когда я пытаюсь вызвать этот метод у наследника js говорит такого метода нету

Пример:

```
function GameObject(){}

GameObject.prototype.set = function() {};

function GameFon() {}
GameFon.prototype = GameObject;
GameFon.prototype.constructor = GameFon;

var fon = new GameFon();

fon.set(); //здесь возникает ошибка
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сейчас проще пользоваться транслятором es6, чем не пользоваться es6

```js
'use strict'

class GameObject {
   set(value) {
     this._value = value;
   }
   get() {
     return this._value;
   }
}

class GameFon extends GameObject {
  test() {
    this.set("Hello Class");
    console.log(this.get());
  }
}

new GameFon().test()
```

(работает в не древних хромах.)

Comment: В целях саморазвития, и экспериментальных подходов к дизайну, могу посоветовать почитать статью про 3D кубы, http://originalip.ru/?L=58 ссылка на первоисточник (EN) вы сможете найти в конце стать. Всего хорошего!

Comment: я что-то не понял как он к теме относится, они вообще по-моему перемудрили с реализацией.

Comment: Ужасный способ.

Comment: А ну да 3 года назад однако. Я не помню, может там что то подходило для конкретного случая

Comment: @Qwertiy А может и вовсе не я написал, истории правок нет, а выглядит чушью даже на три года назад,

Comment: @zb', это был один из способов, но плохой. Версию с классами лучше запостить отдельным ответом, а этот не менять. Да и поддержка у классов пока не очень.

Comment: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-class

поддержка в хроме полностью с 49, в strict mode с 46, частично в strict mode в 41, FF с 45, Edge 13, т.е. все мажорные браузеры в стабильной версии поддерживают все фичи классов без strict, как то так. Не очень плохая поддержка. для остальных можно делать билды с использованием трансформеров.

Answer (score 1):

Надо класть в прототип промежуточный объект, основанный на прототипе базового класса:

> ```
> GameFon.prototype = GameObject;
> ```

```
GameFon.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype);
```

Comment: Вообще сейчас уже просто class extend